# ASP.NET MVC Facebook Style friend tags in textbox

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am not sure what it is called, but I am trying to replicate the facebook style tagging of friends in a post.

I would like it that when I start to type one of my customers names in, that it prompts to add the customer name to the post and is a hyperlink to the customer profile.

Anyone know what this might be called, or a way to achieve this?

Thanks
Mike

Comment: I think a lot more information will be needed. You might also want to fix what you're doing to the customer name in the second paragraph.

Comment: This can be implemented using an javascript 'autocomplete' field or [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html#tags)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, It is just a auto complete text box. As you type, Your code should read the text in the textbox, send it to some server page/api endpoints with this text and other relevant information needed. The server page will query your db table and return your friends name in a list to the caller and you need to display it in a list under the text box. You should have code when user select one item from that list to invoke some other js function where you will save it again to the db table (of tagged people) table.

Fortunately there are a lot of plugins available to do this. With minimal customization, you can achieve this. [jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) is a library you can look into. It has an [Auto complete](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) feature. There are a lot of other libraries too. A simple google search will help you to get started.